# NGINX Rewrite for Latin character

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I need to add a NGINX rewrite to replace "İ" (Capital I with dot on top) with a regular "i" in URLs with following pattern:

- [https://example.com/tİf-to-tiff](https://example.com/t%C4%B0f-to-tiff)
- [https://example.com/tİf-to-İco](https://example.com/t%C4%B0f-to-%C4%B0co)
- [https://example.com/doc-to-dİf](https://example.com/doc-to-d%C4%B0f)

I was able to capture "İ" with (?:[\x{130}]) as follows:

https://regex101.com/r/ZfWlGa/1

When translated to NGINX rewrite as follows. It does not work.

**rewrite (.)(?:[\x{130}])(.) $1i$2 permanent;**

Also tried the opposite approach, that is to find non-ASCII characters and replace with "i" as follows. It does not work either.

https://regex101.com/r/VxBB30/1

What is correct way to do it?

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^(.*)\xC4\xB0(.*)$ $1i$2 permanent;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Nginx regular expression syntax supports the Unicode code point notation. You can instead write the code point as two octets. `U+0130` is represented in UTF8 as the two octets `C4` and `B0`.

For example:

```
rewrite ^(.*)\xC4\xB0(.*)$ $1i$2 permanent;
```